# Linking error in pcl EuclideanClusterExtraction

Tags: c++, static-linking, point-cloud-library

I am having the strangest linking error when trying to run the example provided by pcl:

http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php

I have narrowed the error down to the following line:

```
ec.extract (cluster_indices);
```

When i remove this line there are no linking errors otherwise i get a bunch that look like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpcl_search.a(organized.cpp.o): In function `pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZL>::computeCameraMatrix(Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3>&) const':
organized.cpp:(.text._ZNK3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_9PointXYZLEE19computeCameraMatrixERN5Eigen6MatrixIfLi3ELi3ELi0ELi3ELi3EEE
[_ZNK3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_9PointXYZLEE19computeCameraMatrixERN5Eigen6MatrixIfLi3ELi3ELi0ELi3ELi3EEE]+0xc): 
undefined reference to `pcl::getCameraMatrixFromProjectionMatrix(Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4> const&, Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3>&)'
```

`ec` is of the type `pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction<pcl::PointXYZ>` and all of the ascociated point clouds are also use the `pcl::PointXYZ` template. This is all directly out of the example.

I have had a very similar error before and it turned out to be because I was attempting to use the `pcl::PointXY` with the `SampleConsesus` library which is not supported.

To attempt to solve this problem I used `nm` on the `libpcl_search.a` link library and the values included look like this:

```
_ZNK3pcl6search17OrganizedNeighborINS_11PointNormalEE19computeCameraMatrixERN5Eigen6MatrixIfLi3ELi3ELi0ELi3ELi3EEE
```

which are close to the include funcitons needed, but it seems like the `PointXYZ` implementation doesn't exist?  How can i find out if this is the case and why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SO it looks like cmake is struggling with the dependencies. The reason I am sure is because of the way we are forced to include pcl. We are using an operating system called `QNX` which means that the `CMakeLists.txt` needs to look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/qnx650/host/qnx6/x86/usr/bin/gcc)
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/qnx650/host/qnx6/x86/usr/bin/g++)

project(cluster_extraction)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)

include_directories(/usr/local/include /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7)
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable (cluster_extraction testEuclideanclustering.cpp)
target_link_libraries (cluster_extraction ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

If I add the direct link to `pcl_search` after the link of `${PCL_LIBRARIES}` then it will compile. It seems like we need to make our own `cmake` rules for `pcl`.